# Why the answer to $\log(x+3)+\log(x+2)\geq \log 12$ different from that of $\log(x^2+5x+6)\geq \log12$?

Tags: inequality, logarithms

When I have problem with $\log_b(x^2+2ax+a^2)\geq\log_bk$ I usually just
say that $x^2+2ax+a^2\geq k$ and $x^2+2ax+a^2>0$.

I used in example a $(x+a)^2$ to make the things easy.

So I do the intersection and take the answer, what makes sense to me
and usually works.

But let us suppose that $ b>1$.

In my example I supposed that $\log(x+3)+\log(x+2)=\log(x^2+5x+6)$.

So I didn't do that $x>-3$ and $x>-2$.

I just did that $x^2-5x+6>=12$ and $x^2-5x+6>=0$

This gives me $x>1$ or $x<-6$

And $\log(x+3)+\log(x+2)\geq\log 12$, gives $x>1$ what is the
intersection among $x>-3$ and $x>-2$ and $x^2-5x+6.$

It means that when I should answer a question like

$\log_b(x^2+2ax+a^2)>\log_b(K)$, turning the $\log_b(x^2+2ax+a^2)$
in $\log_b(x+a)+\log_b(x+a)>\log_b(K)$.

So make the intersection between all condictions and results?

How to know if $\log_b(x^2+2ax+a^2)$ is not $\log_b(-x-a)+\log_b(-x-a)$? 
In inequality that gives a different result.

Why does this happen and how to solve these kinds of questions in the "right way"?

Comment: $\log(ab)=\log(a)+\log(b)$, whenever the logs are defined. The missing condition in the inequality is to impose that the logarithms exist.

Comment: Why log(x^2), log(x)+log(x) and log(-x)+log(-x) are different functions?

Comment: They have different domains. The first's $x\neq0$, the second's $x>0$, the third's $x<0$.

Comment: I guess I will have to go to English Stack Exchange. 

It is "The firs's ..." or "The first's is ..."?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To put it simply: the map $\color{blue}{\rm stuff} \mapsto \log_b \color{blue}{\rm stuff}$ is only defined for $\color{blue}{\rm stuff} > 0$, and everything has to be well-defined *a priori*.

- the first equation is defined only if $x+3 > 0$ **and** $x + 2 > 0$, that is, $x > -2$ (the stronger condition).
- the second equation is defined only if $x^2+5x + 6 > 0$, that is, if $x < -3$ **or** $x > -2$.